# Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"IR"} in concatenation

Tags: perl

I'm trying to execute a shell script from one server(plantz1). While executing, I have written the script in such a way that it should log in to another system (globez1) and in that second system, one perl script should be running. But i'm getting errors like below:
Please help me somebody on this. Below, I'm taking the commands from the script and showing you the o/p.

```
plantz1:nyop% ssh globez1 "export PATH=/ilx/ops/sbin:$PATH; /ilx/ops/sbin/mklive_pour ewh drop"
Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"IR"} in concatenation (.) or string at /ilx/ops/sbin/mklive_pour line 25.
Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"IR"} in concatenation (.) or string at /ilx/ops/sbin/mklive_pour line 25.
Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"IR"} in concatenation (.) or string at /ilx/ops/sbin/mklive_pour line 69.
Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"IR"} in concatenation (.) or string at /ilx/ops/sbin/mklive_pour line 69.
No symon.def file? :No such file or directory at /ilx/ops/sbin/mklive_pour line 69.
```

plantz1 is first server
globez1 is secondary server
/ilx/ops/sbin/mklive_pour - it's the perl script

Comment: Not set in the sense ?
How to set it then ?

Answer (score 0):

The `%ENV` hash contains the environment variables from the operating system environment that started your process. `$ENV{IR}` contains the value of the `IR` environment variable. The warning you are getting is telling you that this variable has not been set.

You need to set this variable before running your command. It looks like you're running Linux, so something like this will work:

```
plantz1:nyop% export IR=something
```

Unfortunately, as I don't know anything about the software you're trying to use, I can't give you any help as to what the value of that variable needs to be.